# How to get item id from a list view webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, jquery

I have a calculated column with html button where i am calling the java script. On this button click i want to get the ID of the share point list item.

I dont want to use desiner workflows to copy the id and then use the calculated column. I tried the below Javascript where i was able to fetch the ID after 2nd click of my button

```
function createListItem()
  {
   /* $("table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-itmhover").hover(function(e){       
        var iids = $(this).attr('iid').split(',');
        itemID = iids[1];
        offset = $(this).offset();              
      alert(itemID);
    });}
```

Comment: You can refer this link [how-to-get-selected-item-id-from-sharepoint-2013-list](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/how-to-get-selected-item-id-from-sharepoint-2013-list-21207.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a button.. the whole page will have loaded ... that means you can use a SharePoint function inside the click event handler:

```
var ID=GetAncestor(this,'TR').id.split(',')[1];
```

This goes up to the TR element, and gets the ID **y** from the TR element id: 'x,**y**,z'

Note that '**iid**' is **not** available in GridView, so use '**id**'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I was able to achieve this by  using the below code.
Actually my scenario was to have a html button on document library to download each item

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" ></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


var itemID = "";
var title = "";
var offset = null;
 $('#document').ready(function () {
   $("table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-itmhover").on( "click", function() { 
    // debugger;
     title=$(this).parent().parent().attr('summary');
        var iids = $(this).attr('iid').split(',');
        itemID = iids[1];        
    //alert(itemID + title );    
var getFileName = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + title + "')/items(" + itemID + ")/?$select=EncodedAbsUrl";
$.ajax({
url: getFileName,
type: "GET",
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: function (listData) {
fileURL = listData.d.EncodedAbsUrl; //_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/"+title+"/"+
filename = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
window.location.href=fileURL;
},
error: function (error) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
},
async: false
});

});
    //alert(itemID);
 });

  </script>
```